# What width should I set a UIBarButtonItem to make a square button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, dimensions

I want to have a square button on my toolbar. My `UIBarButtonItem` uses an image which is wide enough to push my button into a rectangular shape. I looked through the docs, but couldn't find the best size to use.

Looking at other answers, `29.0` seems to be a common size, but I'd like to get confirmation. Here's how I set my button up:

```
UIBarButtonItem *locationButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"]
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(locationButtonTapped:)];
[locationButtonItem setWidth:29.0f];
```

What width should I set my toolbar button to be to make it square?

Answer (score 10):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 29, 29);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(locationButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *btnDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
//[btnDone setTarget:self];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnDone;
[btnDone release];
```

Try this ... maybe it will help you.

Comment: can we change the barbuttonitem in storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Just used *UIKit Artwork Extractor* and found out that the `UIBarButtonImage` is a perfect square when the picture inside is 13x16 @1x pixels. I simply measured the "plus" sign button used by `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` style (`UINavigationBarAddButton.png`) and also tried it by myself. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `[locationButton setWidth:locationButton.height];`

Comment: I knew my bad variable naming would get me into trouble. `locationButton` isn't a `UIButton`, it's a `UIBarButtonItem`, which has no height property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the width of UIBarButton.

Instead of that, If you want custom width you will need to use initWithCustomView.

You can use the width property only if button in UIToolbar.